# When I click a button my audio won't play

Tags: javascript, function, audio

I made a button and then made it so it sends `playAudio()` on click of itself.
self.

I tried to get it to send a message to the function to do it, and I think that works fine. I think JavaScript is the part that doesn't work.

```
<body>
    <button class="playAudio" onclick="playAudio()">Play audio</button>
</body>
```

```
const audio = new Audio("C:UsersjbrirDocumentsBowgartWebsite2audioBowgart_sample.mp3e");

function playAudio() {
  audio.play();
}
```

I expected it to play the audio, but it ended up playing nothing.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct file path (without any directory separators)? Besides that, what does your console say? I'd assume there is at least one error.

Comment: No erros in console. I copied path

Comment: Frankly I can't believe this. If you copy the path again in your explorer I bet you can't open the file. How would that work? The file name would be `UsersjbrirDocumentsBowgartWebsite2audioBowgart_sample.mp3e`..

Comment: It might be an extension I have on VS. I have the same problem for a few other things too. I switched it to an audio element in html.

Comment: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" It  only cant find my images when I try to change their src with a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the issue in the path.

Please try to do like this, `C:/.../file.mp3`

code.

```
<button class="playAudio" onclick="playAudio()">Play audio</button>

<script>const audio = new Audio(
    "C:/Users/jbrirDocumentsBowgartWebsite2audioBowgart_sample.mp3"
  );
  
  function playAudio() {
    audio.play();
  }</script>
```